# Programatically place TextViews underneath eachother in a RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layoutparams

## Problem

---

I've been trying to place a couple of `TextView`s underneath eachother, but I can't seem to get it working. They always overlap eachother in stead of getting placed beneath eachother.

## What have I tried

---

I've tried messing with gravity (which doesn't work with a `RelativeLayout`), and all sorts of layout parameters. I've concluded that the best solution for me would be to use the `RelativeLayout.BELOW` parameter. The only problem is I'm trying to find the id of the previous `TextView`.  
I assign the id's for the `TextView`s using the iterator. It seems I can't use the iterator - 1 to count as an id (even though other answers on SO suggest this works). I've even tried assigning the current `TextView` to a "previous_tv" variable to use in the next iteration.  
I tried finding the `TextView` I just placed using `this.findViewByID` and the correct iterator value for the id, this also did not work.

## Code

---

I'm trying to figure out what I should place as an id for my parameter rule. This is the code I'm reffering to -edit, placed full code as per request-:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //Don't show application name on the top of the screen (valuable space)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_play); //Set which layout file to use for this activity

    //Get the Task that was sent by TaskActivity
    this.task = (Task) this.getIntent().getSerializableExtra("TASK_OBJECT");
    //Get the Sums for this Task
    this.sums = this.task.getSums();

    //GridView setup
    this.gridview = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.gridView_task_play);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = this.task.getArrayAdapterForGridView(this);

    this.gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    //TextView setup
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.activity_task_play_relative);

    for(int i = 0; i < this.sums.length; i++)
    {
        //Layout parameters
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        //This variable counts how many times the placeholder text is skipped and a operator (+-/ etc.) is placed in the sum_text.
        //This is usefull for placing the correct placeholder for each number in the sum (a, b, c etc.)
        int times_skipped = 0; 

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        String sum_text = "";

        for(int j = 0; j < this.sums[i].getVariables().length; j++)
        {               
            if(this.isParsable(this.sums[i].getVariables()[j]))
            {
                sum_text += TaskPlayActivity.PLACEHOLDERS[(j - times_skipped)] + " ";
            }
            else
            {
                sum_text += this.sums[i].getVariables()[j] + " ";
                times_skipped++;
            }
        }

        if(i > 0) 
        {
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, i - 1);
        }
        tv.setId(i);
        tv.setText(sum_text + "= " + this.sums[i].getAnswer());
        tv.setTextColor(TaskPlayActivity.COLOURS[i]);
        tv.setTextSize(25);
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(tv);
    }
}
```

## XML

Added the XML. I'm not very good in layouts so it could very well be that the fault resides here.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/activity_task_play_relative"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="220dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView_task_play"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#EFEFEF"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:paddingTop="1dp"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp" >

        </GridView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any other suggestions are welcome as well, though I would prefer keeping a `RelativeLayout`. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [View#setId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) says the identifier should be a positive number so you should make sure not to use zero as identifier value.

Also you have to create a new LayoutParams instance for each TextView. As it is all your TextViews share the same LayoutParams object and changes to that one object affect all TextViews.

And you could use [View#generateViewId](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId%28%29) to generate an ID and remember the ID of the last iteration.

Comment: generateViewId requires me to move to a higher API. I would rather not do this unless it is really necesary.

Comment: I think the main problem is your reuse of the LayoutParams object (I edited my answer once I noticed that).

Comment: Thanks, I edited that and I actually thought it might solve it (fallen for that mistake so many times) but unfortunately it did not.

Comment: The implementation of generateViewId() seems to be concerned with not returning zero, maybe you should start with 1.

Comment: Wow... That actually did it, thanks! If you edit your answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are calling this code in a loop. In that case just put `i - 1` (previous view id) as id for the rule.

Comment: However, this should work. Can you post your full code (with the loop), so that we could figure out why ?